# CSS issue - Background-Color not responding in - Magento style.css

Tags: css, magento, background-color

I am trying to change the background color of the Shopping Cart title block.

When I added

```
background-color: #;
```

to

```
.block-cart { 
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 width: 165px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 top: -33px;
 right: 10px;
}
```

It showed a blue line, but not whole background.

Following block appears to be overlapping ^

```
.block-cart .block-title { 
     height: 7px;
     background-color: !important;

}
```

The background-color element in ^ is not changing the color at all. I tried without !important first, but it made no difference.

Please give some suggestions or ideas as to why it's not loading!

Thanks!

Comment: Check if there is also a background image. If so, remove that

Comment: HI, there is no background image as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `height: 30px;`. The actual block height clearly exceeds 30px. Removing that line should fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, the header got bigger after removing the height. No other changes. ".block-cart .block-title" appears to be the top layer which is the color gray. I don't know why it's not responding to background-color command. Any other ideas? Thanks for the help

Comment: Use `background` instead of `background-color`. The gray color is defined somewhere else using `background`, so you need to use the same name in order to overwrite it.